# about iOS localization

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

In the following doc:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html

it's mentioned that

> *In iOS, the bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script information
>   into account when looking for
>   localized resources; only the language
>   designator code is considered.
>   Therefore if your project includes
>   language-specific project directories
>   with both a language and region
>   designator, those directories are
>   ignored. The bundle interfaces in Mac
>   OS X do support region designators in
>   language-specific project
>   directories.*

I don't quite understand this. Does it mean that the name of .lproj directory cannot contain any region code?
But at least I know that iOS accepts zh_TW.lproj, zh_CN.lproj. How about en_GB.lproj and en-GB_GB.lproj? Or it only knows en.lproj?

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that iOS would support only two digit language codes (e.g. en.lproj, es.lproj etc.). Whereas Mac OS X will support the format Language_Region (e.g. en_GB, en_US etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I think that information is outdated. They must not have updated the Mac development docs when the iOS changes were made.

When you're creating your Localizable.strings or Project.plist file, you will create one per language or language-dialect. Just create the ones you need.

If you're using Xcode 4, be sure to show the "Utilities" (View-->Utilities-->Show Utilities) when the Localizable.strings or Project.plist file is selected. It will have a Localization section that makes adding these easy.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that info is completely outdated. Trying to create a dialect, say Portuguese-Brazilian, using Xcode 4 generates a Localizable.strings file under pt-BR, but changing it to Settings->General->International->Language->Portuguese AND International->Region->Brazil does NOT work, causing the strings to either default to English or plain Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: As of iOS 8 you can now use any language or region in iOS.**

Apophenia is correct. Although iOS has 30 languages that it will recognize as .lproj folders, it won't accept any regional codes, so telling it **fr-CA** won't get you French Canadian, but rather will simply use your French or English strings. The only exception to this rule is Chinese, which should be *zh-Hans* for Simplified Chinese and *zh-Hant* for Traditional Chinese.

You should always use the two-letter code for the language (en.lproj, fr.lproj, es.lproj, de.lproj, and so on).

There is a complete (and updated) list of the current supported languages and language codes for both iOS and iTunes here:

http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html

Note that the iTunes App Store has a different list of supported languages, which makes the chart linked to above very handy!

Comment: Does this mean that you *cannot* provide different localizations in iOS for, say, French (France) and French (Canada)? This is still true in iOS 7+?

Comment: As of iOS 8 and Xcode 6, Apple allows iOS apps to use any language and region. http://ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2014/06/new-xcode-6-localization-ios-y…