# Is it possible to localize the application name based on a criterion other than language?

Tags: ios, localization

Thanks to @Jano, I know how to localize application strings based on the country in which the application is running - in my question : [How to localize text based on criterion other than language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163839/how-to-localize-text-based-on-criterion-other-than-language). The answer is to take these strings out of the Settings.bundle and bring them into the application, where they can be localized in whatever manner the developer requires.

My question now is: is it possible to localize the application name (the name under the app icon) using a criterion other than language?  I think that doing this on a language basis is well understood - there are several questions and answers on Stack Overflow and elsewhere which discuss localizing the BundleDisplayName.

But my customer would like to give the application a different name in the various European countries in which he expects to market it, and some of these countries (Germany, Austria, Switzerland), share a language.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode allow you to add de-AT, de-DE and de-CH localization files, but I have just tried this out and looks like it has no effect. I tried to change device language to German and then switch region format between Austria, Germany and Switzerland, but the bundle display name didn't change from English. When I added de (without a -XX suffix for country) it changed to German name, again ignoring region format. I'm a bit confused as I was under impression we could use those country-specific localizations like that. I hope someone offers a better solution, but until then I would suggest a workaround: building 3 targets, one for each country, and submitting them to AppStore and only making them available in their respective countries.

Comment: Thanks, @fichek.  It looks as though the region-specific localization files (de-AT etc) are not supported in iOS, although they are in MacOS. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html, as referenced in the SO question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320407/about-ios-localization

Comment: That's really sad if 5th major OS release will come out in a few weeks without support for this. I'm gonna submit a bug report requesting this feature, I suggest you do the same.